# Why does a ConnectableFlux hang with a late subscriber?

Tags: project-reactor

A 2nd late subscriber to a  `Flux.publish()` just hangs my pipeline, instead of issuing a complete signal. This seems to be a weird behavior to have and seems like a bug to me.

```
  @Test
  void hotSource() throws Exception {
    var flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .flatMap(i -> Mono.<Integer>empty()) // Real code does this based on input+state
        .map(i -> i + 10)
        .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("first part complete"))
        .publish();

    var map = flux
        .collectMap(Function.identity(), Object::toString)
        .doOnSuccess(m -> System.out.println("flux completed " + m));

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    var count = map.flatMapMany(
        m -> flux
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("flatMapMany subscribe"))
            .doOnRequest(r -> System.out.println("Requesting " + r))

            // Not printed from here
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("flatMapMany completed"))
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("i: " + i)))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("after i: " + i))
        .count()
        .subscribe(l -> System.out.println("result: " + l), e -> System.out.println("exception: " + e), () -> {
          System.out.println("Completed!");
          latch.countDown();
        });
    flux.connect();
    System.out.println("Awaiting"); // printed
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Test done");
  }
}
```

This test prints the following then hangs, because the published flux accepts both subscriptions but then stops responding to the 2nd one.

```
Awaiting
first part complete
flux completed {}
flatMapMany subscribe
Requesting 9223372036854775807
```

Why is hanging even a good idea here? Seems sending a complete signal, which does not require caching (i.e. not the behavior of `replay()`), is a superior choice. Even refusing the subscription with an exception seems like a better choice.
This is because this can be a subtle issue (not like in my example), possibly depend on a race condition. It is also an unexpected surprise, which are not good when you design APIs. The alternative of just sending a complete signal seems more consistent with the marble diagram.

Moreover, the docs [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux) and [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publish--) say nothing about this behavior, AFAICT, please correct me if I am wrong.